# Storing App Settings in Swift

Tags: swift, design-patterns, core-data

I need to seed my database with some 'core' tables on first load of my application. would the best approach to use NSUserDefaults in my AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults([
        "hasSeededCoreTables": false

        ])
    return true
}
```

Or should I create a 'Settings' entity in core data and have a boolean set in there. I need the flag to persist between launches so that we don't have to overwrite the core tables every time the application relaunches

Comment: i'd go for userDefaults for settings, core Data is more for scaleable dynamic storage

Comment: If you're planning on using Core Data anyway, I find that a "System" table defined as key/value pairs is nice for consistency of data reference.  If not, I wouldn't introduce Core Data just to maintain a flag.

Comment: consistency of data reference? as in app-wide? i was toying with the idea of having all the app settings in a 'System' table as it makes more sense to me  but are there any pros or cons to each of the methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without doubt the way to do this is to use `NSUserDefaults`. Rather than hard-coding the values in the AppDelegate, I would recommend to use a plist and then call `registerDefaults()` with the contents of that file.

I would not advise you to use a Core Data entity to persist user defaults. That's really not what the object graph is for. (From a performance perspective, there is no difference: `NSUserDefaults` is using SQLite, and presumably so is your Core Data store.)

BTW, plists are also often a good way to seed the database proper with actual data such as sample entries.

Answer (score 0):

If you want persistent data even if the user remove your app from his device, used :

```
NSKeyedArchiver
NSKeyedUnarchiver
```

Here a good lib : JNKeychain.
You can find the code source here : https://github.com/jeremangnr/JNKeychain

Create a new class with static class method inside, here an example using JNKeychain, we add and then we remove a key/value to the key chain :

```
#pragma mark - Keychain exemple -
+ (void)JNKExemple
{
    NSString *testKey = @"myTestKey";
    NSString *testValue = @"myTestValue";

    if ([JNKeychain saveValue:testValue forKey:testKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Correctly saved value '%@' for key '%@'", testValue, testKey);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed to save!");
    }

    NSLog(@"Value for key '%@' is: '%@'", testKey, [JNKeychain loadValueForKey:testKey]);

    if ([JNKeychain deleteValueForKey:testKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Deleted value for key '%@'. Value is: %@", testKey, [JNKeychain loadValueForKey:testKey]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed to delete!");
    }
}
```

Comment: i think, if they remove the app it would be ok to have them seed the core tables again, also removing the app is quite handy during development if i need to purge the db and start again. Do you have any examples of NSKeyedArchiver in use?

Comment: thanks, i'm trying not to use any third party libraries on this project but will definitely consider this in the future :)